# If div wider cut left side of div

Tags: css

I couldn't find anything similar that's why I need your help.

I'm trying to do something similar to [this](http://jsbin.com/xeniy/1/edit)

The idea is the inner div floated to left but when it became wider than the parent it's stick to the right side of the parent and part of the left side became hidden. And because the content dynamic I can't just change float when I need that. I tried at least ten different method but still couldn't figure out.

Comment: Could u be more brief couldn't get you exactly.

Comment: So what is the end result you want ?
From what I understand the div should expand depending upon the text ? Right ?

Comment: Width : Auto 
This will do I hope thats what you are looking for.. Didn't get your question properly though.

Comment: @Swaraj : you are late by 20 sec i posted the same answer ;) :p

Comment: Sander figured out what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
<div id="first">
  <div>
    Hello World!
  </div>
</div>
<div id="second">
  <div>
    Hello World! Hello World!
  </div>
</div>
```

By putting in an extra div, you can get the result you want, adding the following CSS:

```
body > div > div {
  min-width: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

Because of the minimum width, the text will stay to the left, unless it becomes bigger than it's container. Apart from that, nothing is changed.

See the edited [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sedifawu/1/edit)